# US American citizen living in the EU (Schengen Area) working for a UK-based company

Tags: visa, working-visas, us-citizens, schengen

I'm exploring a job transfer opportunity within my organization that would involve working for the UK branch of my US-based company (incorporated as a UK org). I'm interested in living within and telecommuting from the Schengen Area, not the UK.

I could use some insight into the mechanics behind this, if achievable. I assume my family and I would need to petition for residency and cite this company as the means for sustaining ourselves? Is there a mechanism that would allow my spouse to work legally in-country as well?

I understand this is rather vague, as I haven't specified the destination country.

Comment: Most employment-based visas require an employer sponsor.  As far as I'm aware, that sponsor needs to be in the country from which you're applying for a visa.  But the relevant legislation is almost entirely at the national level, not the EU level, so you're far more likely to get a useful answer if you can tell us which Schengen country you want to live in.

Comment: @phoog - valid thoughts and as I too reflect on the situation feel that if the company is not directly sponsoring from _within_ the desired country itself the options for myself and the family are more akin to those who wish to immigrate with self-employment/remote work/savings as their means of support. In short, unless the company actually is incorporated within that country it probably doesn't matter if it's US- or UK-based.

Comment: Generally being self employed is quite different from having savings in that you need work authorization to be self employed, even if your clients are outside the country.  In some countries you can set up a business for this purpose, thereby gaining access to a work permit.